# Use component from imported module

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to use product-carousel.module.ts in home component.
My product-carousel module looks like

```
const COMPONENTS = [
  ProductBlockComponent,
  ProductCarouselComponent,
  ProductCarouselContainerComponent
];

@NgModule({
imports: [
  CommonModule,
  RouterModule
],
declarations: COMPONENTS,
providers: [],
exports: COMPONENTS
})
export class ProductCarouselContainerModule {}
```

Than I register it in home.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
imports: [
  ProductCarouselContainerModule,
  CommonModule,
  FormsModule,
  ProductCarouselContainerModule,
  ComponentsModule,
  ]),
 ],
 declarations: [
  HomeContainer
 ],
 providers: [
   ProductApiService
 ]
})
export class HomeModule {}
```

I want to use ProductCarouselContainerComponent. It has selector 'offer-carousel'. In home component I using it like this

```
<div class="container-fluid currently-funding">
   <product-carousel></product-carousel>
</div>
```

And as result I have

> Error: Template parse errors: 'Product-carousel' is not a known element: 1. If 'offer-carousel' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module. 2. If 'Product-carousel' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA

What I missed?

Comment: Its confusing. home.module.ts is component. Right? If yes please name it as home.component.ts. For better understanding.

Comment: @TavishAggarwal home.module.ts - it's a module, which contains some components. And I want to use one from it. It's named OfferCarouselContainerComponent and has selector "offer-carousel"

Comment: okay! Looks ok to me.. let me see if I can help you out

Comment: @TavishAggarwal it will be cool. Thank you, buddy

Comment: Be careful to not import twice your `OfferCarouselContainerModule` in your `HomeModule`, but appart from that it looks Ok. In your 3 components, make sure that one has the correct `offer-carousel` selector. It should work. Sending us a GitHub link would be better in that case because a lof of things could cause this issue which is hard to pinpoint

Comment: @AlexBeugnet give me 1 second

Comment: @AlexBeugnet link to repo
https://github.com/ibogdan94/angular4

What to use offer/offer-carousel.module/ts inside home component. home.component.html, line 14 give me an error (<offer-carousel></offer-carousel>)

Comment: You are missing the `"@ngrx/effects": "^4.0.4",` library in your `package.json` by the way :-)

Comment: @AlexBeugnet looks like I installed it, but forget to use --save flag. Thank you. Do you see any errors?

Comment: Yes, but it is caused because of your `package.json` file... I'm getting the error : `Cannot assign to read only property 'microTask' of object '[object Object]'` most probably caused by `ngrx-store-freeze`. What is your current version of this library ? Consider freezing the versions of the packages you are using for the github.

Comment: Must be because a new release was there 2 days ago with breaking changes I suppose : https://github.com/brandonroberts/ngrx-store-freeze/releases

Comment: @AlexBeugnet
from package
  "name": "ngrx-store-freeze",
  "optionalDependencies": {},
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@ngrx/store": "^2.2.1"
  },
  "readme": "ERROR: No README data found!",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/codewareio/ngrx-store-freeze.git"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rm -rf dist && tsc",
    "lint": "tslint 'src/**/*.ts'",
    "prepublish": "npm run build && npm run lint"
  },
  "typings": "./dist/index.d.ts",
  "version": "0.1.9"

Comment: @AlexBeugnet I have the same message. And error message I found here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/k9kyrvhx3dzew1r/Selection_040.jpg?dl=0

Comment: Yes, there is an incompatibility between `@ngrx` and `ngrx-store-freeze`. You just updated your packages I guess to have it :-). There is an open issue right there : https://github.com/brandonroberts/ngrx-store-freeze/issues/17.
Kinda hard to spot the actual bug with these stores messing with us :-D

Comment: Alright, to set this `ngrx-store-freeze` issue aside, you can change this in the file `src/app/reducers/index.ts` : `? [logger, storeFreeze]` to `? [logger]` at line 63

Comment: @AlexBeugnet I remove it from app/reducers/index.ts but still has issue about 'offer-carousel' is not a known element

Comment: @AlexBeugnet Now I have the same error, but more beautiful
https://www.dropbox.com/s/qkamvds3vp24yss/Selection_041.jpg?dl=0

Comment: yes, the main issue is not corrected, I get the correct error message now

Comment: Did you solve the issue or i can write the answer?

Comment: I'm writing it atm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is actually displayed in your screenshot. The issue is that the `HomeComponent` is declared in the `ComponentsModule` and not in the `HomeModule`.

Changing this in your `ComponentsModule` will make it work (well there is an async pipe error but that's something else obviously) :

**app/home/components/index.ts :**

```
import { OfferCarouselModule } from './../../offer/offer-carousel.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CarouselModule.forRoot(),
    CommonModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule,
    SlickModule,
    OfferCarouselModule
  ],
  declarations: COMPONENTS,
  exports: COMPONENTS,
})
export class ComponentsModule { }
```

Comment: But it's still a bizarre way of architecture, because you have Home containers, with HomeComponents, and barrels used as modules, etc... This requires a bit of cleanup I believe...

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your comment

Comment: No problem mate it's fine

Comment: Yes, the project is a mess tbh :D